# SNMP installation and configuration recursive script

Tags: powershell

I have to install and configure the SNMP service on many servers and I have prepared a powershell script to perform the operations recursively by taking the names of the various servers from a text file. Apparently the script works but with the exception of the server from which the script is launched, no one else installs the service. I am attaching the script that I use and ask those who know more than me to tell me the error. Thanks in advance.

```
$pollers = @("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX") # indirizzi ip Pollers (IP o DNS name) - esempio: @("monitorserv1","10.10.5.2")
 $CommunityStr = @("NOME_COMMUNITY") # nome community - esempio:  @("Secretcommunity","private2")

 Import-Module ServerManager

 #foreach ($ServerName in Get-Content .\Listaservers.txt){

    Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $ServerName

 #testo se SNMP VMI è installato
 $test = Get-WindowsFeature -ComputerName $ServerName -Name SNMP-Service

 #Installa/abilita SNMP-Service se il test precedente fallisce
 If ($test.Installed -ne "True") {
 Write-Host "Installo SNMP-Service su $ServerName..."
 Get-WindowsFeature -name SNMP* | Add-WindowsFeature -IncludeManagementTools | Out-Null
 }

 #ri-testo se SNMP-Service Feature è abilitato ed aggiorno le variabili
 $test = Get-WindowsFeature -Name SNMP-Service

 #scrivo le chiavi di registro se SNMP-Service è attivo
 If ($test.Installed -eq "True"){
 Write-Host "Configuro SNMP-Services con la stringa Community e gli indirizzi pollers"
 #Setto SNMP Permitted Manager(s) ** ATTENZIONE : questa operazione sovrascrive i parametri attuali **
  reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\PermittedManagers" /v 1 /t REG_SZ /d localhost /f | Out-Null

 #Setto SNMP Traps e SNMP Community in *Read Only*
 Foreach ($String in $CommunityStr){
 reg add ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\" + $String) /f | Out-Null
 # Setto la Default value a null
 reg delete ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\" + $String) /ve /f | Out-Null
 reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\ValidCommunities" /v $String /t REG_DWORD /d 4 /f | Out-Null

 $i = 2
 Foreach ($manager in $pollers){
 reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\PermittedManagers" /v $i /t REG_SZ /d $manager /f | Out-Null
 reg add ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\" + $String) /v $i /t REG_SZ /d $manager /f | Out-Null
 $i++
 }
 }
 }
 #riavvio il servizio dopo averlo configurato
 Restart-Service "SNMP"
{
 Write-Host "Configurazione completata"
 }
```

Comment: Use `$true` and `$false` instead of the strings `"True"` and `"False"`. Or as `if ($test.Installed) { … }`.

Answer (score 0):

It works on the local computer only  because after `Enter-pssession` the remote session cannot access the variables you have defined locally.

I have edited your script changing the remote execution method and pulling in local variables with `$using:variable`.

**Note**: I did not test the actual script logic of installing and configuring SNMP.

```
$pollers = @("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX") # indirizzi ip Pollers (IP o DNS name) - esempio: @("monitorserv1","10.10.5.2")
$CommunityStr = @("NOME_COMMUNITY") # nome community - esempio:  @("Secretcommunity","private2")

$installSNMPsb = { 
     Import-Module ServerManager

     #testo se SNMP VMI è installato
     $test = Get-WindowsFeature -Name SNMP-Service

     #Installa/abilita SNMP-Service se il test precedente fallisce
     If ($test.Installed -ne "True") {
         Write-Host "Installo SNMP-Service su $ServerName..."
         Get-WindowsFeature -name SNMP* | Add-WindowsFeature -IncludeManagementTools | Out-Null
     }

     #ri-testo se SNMP-Service Feature è abilitato ed aggiorno le variabili
     $test = Get-WindowsFeature -Name SNMP-Service

     #scrivo le chiavi di registro se SNMP-Service è attivo
     If ($test.Installed -eq "True"){
         Write-Host "Configuro SNMP-Services con la stringa Community e gli indirizzi pollers"
         #Setto SNMP Permitted Manager(s) ** ATTENZIONE : questa operazione sovrascrive i parametri attuali **
          reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\PermittedManagers" /v 1 /t REG_SZ /d localhost /f | Out-Null

         #Setto SNMP Traps e SNMP Community in *Read Only*
         Foreach ($String in $using:CommunityStr){
             reg add ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\" + $String) /f | Out-Null
             # Setto la Default value a null
             reg delete ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\" + $String) /ve /f | Out-Null
             reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\ValidCommunities" /v $String /t REG_DWORD /d 4 /f | Out-Null

             $i = 2
             Foreach ($manager in $using:pollers){
                 reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\PermittedManagers" /v $i /t REG_SZ /d $manager /f | Out-Null
                 reg add ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\" + $String) /v $i /t REG_SZ /d $manager /f | Out-Null
                 $i++
             }
         }
     }
     #riavvio il servizio dopo averlo configurato
     Restart-Service "SNMP"
     Write-Host "Configurazione completata"
}

 foreach ($ServerName in $(Get-Content .\Listaservers.txt)){
    invoke-command -ScriptBlock $installSNMPsb -ComputerName $ServerName
}
```